# Good practices with exception handling

Tags: python, exception

I would like to have some advice with good practices on exception handling in Python.

If I take a simple program that uses the `socket` library for example, I would have a block of code like this:

```py
try:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 6666))
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno == 98:
        log.error('Address already in use')
    else:
        raise
```

My question is: is it interesting to process the exception like this, as I could simply raise it and the stack trace would be printed in my log file ?

My opinion is that if the exception is not handled with a particular process (like calling a specific function, or updating some context or whatever), I'm not getting the point of just logging a message that is exactly what I would have by just raising the exception.

But in the same time, I think a clean code should catch *obvious* exceptions that could come up, and try to handle every other type of exception in a generic `except` clause, just in case.

What is your point of view on this particular question ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can provide a cleaner error message than a full stack trace, and the code you show can *continue* if the `OSError` reports error 98, as by not reraising it you have promised that the exception has been handled.

Comment: Use `errno.EADDRINUSE` instead of 98, as the actual error number may be platform-specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO - You don't need to catch/raise exceptions all over the place. Its normal to let exceptions propagate further up the stack to higher level code. Your example is strange in that errno 60 is logged and then ignored. You'll get another exception when you try to use the unbound socket later on. If you are doing catch/log/raise without other cleanup work, then you likely didn't need that handler at all.

It really comes down to being exception aware when designing and writing the code. Suppose this is a support function for a larger function `send_file` that sends a file to a remote server. Lets say `send_file` uses 10 functions to get the job done. The thing that calls `send_file` really only cares about success/failure. It would be reasonable to skip exception handling in those 10 functions completely and have `send_file` catch everything relevant.

Those 10 functions that don't catch exceptions would have to be coded with that knowledge in mind. For instance, would any one call that can raise on exception leave the system in a bad state? Is any cleanup needed? Should some of those functions really be context managers that cleanup on exit?

And be careful about catching everything because you may mask undetected bugs in your code. `send_file` may have a list of known problems that it catches and returns `False`, but raise an exception for the unkown unknowns so that the overall program can pull the fire alarm and exit completely.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine your `try` statement is in the body of a loop, that tries binding to various addresses until you find one that is available. In that case, the exception raised in the event of an address already being in use is fully "handled" by acknowledging that it happened and moving on to the next possible address.

```
addresses_to_try = [...]

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

for address in addresses_to_try:
    try:
        sock.bind(address, 6666)
        break
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno == errno.EADDRINUSE:
            log.warning("%s already in use, trying the next address", address)
        else:
            raise
else:
    raise OSError(errno.EADDRINUSE, "All addresses in use")
```

Handling the exception can also mean that you *know* there is no way to recover from the error, and you absolutely need to exit the program. Re-raising the exception simply says that you don't know how to recover
from the error *here*, but someone higher in the call stack may know how, and you are giving them the opportunity to do so.

```
try:
    sock.bind(address, 6666)
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno == errno.EADDRINUSE:
        sys.exit("The only and only possible address is not available")
    else:
        log.error("Something when wrong binding to %s", address)
        log.error("Maybe someone else can do something about it.")
        raise
```